# How J2EE Agent contacts OpenAm?

Tags: openam, cross-domain-policy, opensso

I have installed OpenAM in domain 1, and my application is in domain 2 protected with J2EE agent,My question is, Once I get access to my application after authentication do the agent contacts over the network to openam(for authorization), for every click I make on my application,If the answer is yes than what will be the performance impact if my agent and openam is in two domains which are geographically separated, If the answer is no,how does an agent invalidates an access to my application,when admin invalidates a user session from openAm home page.

Comment: Hi i am newbie struggling for weeks know to setup webagent with open for ldap authentication please ping me mail id so that i can contact u for some assistance

Answer (score 1):

The agent needs to communicate with OpenAM for authorization decisions, but it will cache the resulting decision so subsequent evaluations will be local.

OpenAM can call back the agent in the container (that is what agentapp.war is for). This can be used to notify the agent that the users session is no longer valid. For example, if they logged out of OpenAM, or their session expired.

The performance impact will be very small. OpenAM is supporting installations with tens of millions of users - so unless your site is very large this will not be an issue.

You generally want to localize the agent to OpenAM traffic to the same data center when possible. If you had multiple regions you would want to have OpenAM instances in those regions. They can be configured to fail over to each other if required.

Comment: #Warren Strange  but I have not deployed agentapp.war in webapps so in that case how the invalidate session is working.

Comment: is it possible that agent do not communicate with OpenAm at all through back channeling if I tell agent I don't want agent to do any policy verification.

Comment: Agents must poll OpenAM if agentapp is not deployed. agentapp allows OpenAM call back to the agent immediately to notify the agent of a change.

Comment: The agent must always be able to communicate (via polling or notification) to the OpenAM server - even if you are not doing policy verification (e.g. SSO only mode).

Comment: if I go for the notification approach than how openam is going to notify my agent if application are distributed in different geographical location,sitting behind a load balancer,I guess sticky session wont solve this problem as application is not sending any request?

Comment: if all the apps are known by the same dns

Comment: OpenAM sets a cookie that identifies the node that originally authenticated the user. OpenAM can forward the request to another instance.

Comment: #Warren I can see their is a continuous polling still happens from agent as:[19/Jan/2014:10:51:47 +0530] "GET /openam/namingservice HTTP/1.1" 200 991, can this be stopped?

Comment: This is all covered in the documentation. Please read it. See http://openam.forgerock.org/openam-documentation/openam-doc-source/doc/admin-guide/index/chap-agents.html

Comment: actually it is something getting picked from 
com.iplanet.am.naming.url=http://openam.example.com:8080/openam/namingservice, of "OpenamAgentBootStrapProperties" and getting fired even though I am not accessing any application. I have disabled session and policy polling,as per document and it doesn't poll for them,but no document is speaking about this polling.

Answer (score 1):

By default OpenAM and J2EE Policy Agent communicates in Notification mode so OpenAM would notify (check notificationUrl field in config properties) an agent for any Logout events. Now, as mentioned by @warren-strange a J2EE Policy Agent periodically sends request to OpenAM server and that way it would be able to know if Token exists and is valid.